# Tensors in matrix multiplication algorithms

Tags: matrices, algorithms, computational-complexity, tensor-products, tensors

Fast matrix multiplication algorithms, be it the Winograd and Coppersmith algorithm or any further improvement of it, extensively use tensors. In fact, the entire construction is based on tensor analysis. My question is WHY TENSORS? How do tensors help? The following links provide details of the algorithms:

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/matrixmult.pdf

http://issac-symposium.org/2014/tutorials/ISSAC2014_tutorial_handout_LeGall.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: without reading anything you posted, my glib answer: multilinearity.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Multilinearity, as in? I think I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: In terms of concrete calculation, the tensor product is simply a way to build a basis for the set of multilinear mappings. So, when I see $\otimes$ in your context, my mind immediately jumps to some sort of underlying multilinearity. Apparently, the multilinearity stems from added linearity from each succesive matrix multiplication. For two matrices multiplied bilinearity, for three there is a trilinear map etc. (this I see from the answer posted, I'm no expert in the algorithms you link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, matrix multiplication can be seen as a bilinear map
$$K^{n\times k}\times K^{k\times m}\rightarrow K^{n\times m},$$
where $K$ is the ground field.

Such a bilinear map can be expressed as a tensor of order 3 of format $(nk)\times (km)\times (nm)$ (any bilinear map $K^{\ell_1}\times K^{\ell_2}\rightarrow K^{\ell_3}$ can be represented by a tensor of format $\ell_1\times\ell_2\times\ell_3$).

The number of (non-commutative) multiplications required to compute the bilinear map then corresponds to the rank of this tensor of order 3. This number of multiplications corresponds to the "order" of recursive algorithms to compute this bilinear map. For instance, Strassen's algorithm corresponds to a rank 7 decomposition of the tensor associated to the multiplication of $2\times 2$ matrices, leading to a general algorithm for multiplying $n\times n$ matrices with complexity $O(n^{\log_2(7)})$.

You may be interested in the following classical reference that explains well this relationship: the book "Algebraic Complexity Theory" by Burgisser, Clausen and Shokrollahi.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice explanation.

Comment: @emeu Why can a bilinear map corresponding to matrix multiplication be represented by a tensor in the way described by you? Could you please suggest me some online source for it? Apologies, my question may be very silly, but I'm very new to this subject. Thanks!

Comment: @user258178, check out the Wikipedia article on Strassen's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm.